# NativeModule.require what is this function and where do I find its sources?

Tags: node.js, path

I've been looking into rewriting Node.js to work on Cygwin. I could follow the source code right up to:

```
NativeModule.require('path')
```

`path` is the module I figured I'll have to patch. But I'm not quite sure yet where exactly it is located. Any pointers? I've grep'ed on Node.js headers / cc files, but the word "path" only occurs there once, and it's not related to the path resolution.

So, what is it / where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`path` is a core module, all the core modules are in lib folder and are built into the main binary. If you are checking the binaries (installed files) for `path`, you will not find them.

To modify `path` and use it you will need the [source](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.13/node-v0.10.13.tar.gz) files. Make the changes in it and then [build](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) it from the source. You can see the `path` source [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/path.js).

Comment: I was searching for it in the `src` directory of `npm` install - does it mean npm doesn't load all the sources? I've built Node.js before, although not on Windows, but I hope I'll manage... fingers crossed :)